# Crawl is not running in S3 event mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

When running an AWS Glue crawler that points to S3, the second log entry in CloudWatch is always:

> Crawl is not running in S3 event mode

What is S3 event mode?

The name sounds like some way of getting S3 to invoke Glue for partial crawls after every object upload to the prefix. But as far as I can tell, such functionality does not exist. So what is this log entry referring to?

The closest thing I found in the [Glue documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-product&searchQuery=s3%20event%20mode&this_doc_product=AWS%20Glue#facet_doc_product=AWS%20Glue) was [event based triggers for Glue *jobs*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/logging-and-monitoring.html), but Glue Jobs are different to Glue Crawlers.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Create a Glue Crawler. Choose any configuration. Point it to anywhere in any S3 bucket with any dataset (even an empty one)
2. Run the crawler. It doesn't matter if the crawl fails or succeeds
3. Open the logs for that crawl
4. Look at the second log entry

```
2021-07-01T20:04:39.882+10:00
[6588c8ba-57e2-46e3-94b4-1bc4dfc5957d] BENCHMARK : Running Start Crawl for Crawler my-crawler
2021-07-01T20:04:40.200+10:00
[6588c8ba-57e2-46e3-94b4-1bc4dfc5957d] INFO : Crawl is not running in S3 event mode
```

Comment: "such functionality does not exist"  - it may be not available to customers, but AWS could have worked on that for future.

Comment: Yes it turns out that's the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Support gave me an answer.

S3 Event mode is functionality available internally inside AWS. As I suspected it means S3 triggers crawler crawls for every file upload. But this functionality is not public at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found a solution in this article https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/

In short though the solution was to have aws-glue- before the name of my bucket. So, for example trying to get a crawler to go through a bucket called test-bucket would not work but if I change the name to aws-glue-test-bucket then works.

Comment: I don't have a problem with a Glue crawler that I'm trying to solve. I'm just trying to understand the meaning of this one particular log entry.